# What's the meaning of the following statement from file gproc_lib.erl?

Tags: erlang

When reading github's Project gproc's source code file "gproc_lib.erl", I have faced some problem.
Where could I find some related reference doc for this statement syntax?

```
check_option_f(ets_options)    -> fun check_ets_option/1; **%<----**What's the meaning of this** statement**?
check_option_f(server_options) -> fun check_server_option/1.

check_ets_option({read_concurrency , B}) -> is_boolean(B);
check_ets_option({write_concurrency, B}) -> is_boolean(B);
check_ets_option(_) -> false.

check_server_option({priority, P}) ->
    %% Forbid setting priority to 'low' since that would
    %% surely cause problems. Unsure about 'max'...
    lists:member(P, [normal, high, max]);
check_server_option(_) ->
    %% assume it's a valid spawn option
    true.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fun module:name/arity` is a function value, equivalent to the following:

```
fun(A1,A2,...,AN) -> module:name(A1,A2,...,AN) end
```

where N is the `arity`. In short it is a useful shorthand to pass normal Erlang functions as arguments to other functions which expect a function as an argument.

Example:

To convert a list `List` to a set:

```
lists:foldl(fun sets:add_element/2, sets:new(), List).
```

Equivalent to:

```
lists:foldl(fun (E, S) -> sets:add_element(E, S) end, sets:new(), L).
```

(The latter is the definition used in OTP's `set` module for the `from_list` function.)

More info [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#funs).

Comment: Thank you. If you could tell me which page of the book of "http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/users_guide.html" is related to this topic, it will be better.